# Is there any reason *not* to cache an object's hash?

Tags: python, caching, hash

I've written a class whose `.__hash__()` implementation takes a long time to execute. I've been thinking to cache its hash, and store it in a variable like `._hash` so the `.__hash__()` method would simply return `._hash`. (Which will be computed either at the end of the `.__init__()` or the first time `.__hash__()` is called.)

My reasoning was: "This object is immutable -> Its hash will never change -> I can cache the hash."

But now that got me thinking: You can say the same thing about *any* hashable object. (With the exception of objects whose hash is their id.)

So is there ever a reason *not* to cache an object's hash, except for small objects whose hash computation is very fast?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure, it's fine to cache the hash value. In fact, Python does so for strings itself. The trade-off is between the speed of the hash calculation and the space it takes to save the hash value. That trade-off is for example why tuples don't cache their hash value, but strings do (see [request for enhancement #1462796](http://bugs.python.org/issue1462796)).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned earlier caching the hash may be a desired behavior in certain situations.
Note that **you cannot use [@functools.cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) or [@functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) off the shelf**, you will have to implement the caching yourself.
The reason is that these decorators expect the arguments of the decorated function to be hashable, including `self`, leading to a recursive definition.

Hence, don't be surprised if the following gives you an error:

```py
from functools import cache, lru_cache

class Obj():
    @cache
    def __hash__(self):
        return 42  # or anything else really

o = Obj()
print(hash(o))
```

calling `hash(o)` will exit with the error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

That is because the cache of `Obj.__hash__` is first checking if it has seen the argument `self=o` beforehand, thus checking its internal dictionary for the key `o` (or maybe a tuple that contains `o`, I'm not sure, but the details don't matter), and calling `Obj.__hash__(o)` subsequently.

It took me a while to figure out why this error would pop up, I thought people who are redirected here might be interested as well.

Answer (score -1):

The usual reason is that most objects in Python are mutable, so if the hash depends on the properties, it changes as soon as you change a property. If your class really is an immutable and (all the properties which go into the hash are immutable, too!), then you can cache the hash.

Comment: Of course, if an object is mutable, it's usually a bad idea to implement `__hash__` at all. The only builtin uses of `__hash__` require that the hash be stable.

Comment: No, the default implementation of `__hash__` doesn't return anything different when you change a property on a object. Because by default this is true for any object: `hash(obj) == id(obj) == hash(id(obj))` -- this means objects just take their id as their hash. The id is static, so you could say objects "cache" their hash by default.