# Python hash(-1) == -2

Tags: python

I've always thought that in cpython `hash()` built-in function returns the integer itself for integers. So I was a bit confused, when I found out, that `hash(-1)` is an exception to the rule and returns -2.
Is there any reason for `hash(-1)` to not be equal -1

Comment: tldr: because `-1` is used to signal errors in underlying C function.  full version: http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130454/why-do-1-and-2-both-hash-to-2-in-python