# Two integers have the same hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, hash

I was studying dictionaries and looking for ways to avoid the worst-case O(n) time complexity for get/set/delete operations due to potential hash collisions ([src](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)), and learned that integers always hash to themselves, so collisions shouldn't be an issue if you use ints as the dictionary's keys. However, I was testing this in my terminal and this is what I saw:

```
>>> print hash(4), hash(3), hash(2), hash(1), hash(0), hash(-1), hash(-2), hash(-3), hash(-4)
4 3 2 1 0 -2 -2 -3 -4
>>> hash(-1) == hash(-2)
True
```

That's strange, both `hash(-1) == -2` and `hash(-2) == -2`  so I tried it in a dict:

```
>>> d = {-3: 'a', -2:'b', -1:'c'}
>>> print d
{-1: 'c', -3: 'a', -2: 'b'}
```

Okay, at least the hash collision is handled properly.

Why are there two ints that have the same hash?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130454/why-do-1-and-2-both-hash-to-2-in-cpython) previous question answers the question! Here is the **Tl;dr** version:

> The hash value -1 is reserved (it’s used to flag errors in the C
>   implementation). If the hash algorithm generates this value, we simply
>   use -2 instead.

Comment: Now it all makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!