# Why is CPython's hash(-1) != -1

Tags: python, hash, cpython

It'd seem reasonable to make `int.__hash__` simply return the value. Sure enough, that seems to be how CPython implements it:

```
>>> hash(1)
1
>>> hash(2)
2
>>> hash(123456789)
123456789
>>> hash(-123456789)
-123456789
```

Ok, so does this hold true for <s>all</s> most integer x?

```
>>> [x for x in range(-10000, 10000) if hash(x) != x]
[-1]
```

Huh?

```
>>> hash(-1)
-2
```

Why is `-1` the exception to this rule?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is a python object's hash computed and why is the hash of -1 different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648129/when-is-a-python-objects-hash-computed-and-why-is-the-hash-of-1-different)

Comment: I kind of dispute that hashing an int to itself is reasonable. If you build a hash table and allocate it a space of 40 entries, and you insert a bunch of keys that because of some regularity in your data all happen to be the same % 40, you get a lot of collisions. If you apply some non-identity hash function you get less chance for collisions with data that follows a pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm:

> The hash value -1 is reserved (it’s used to flag errors in the C implementation). If the hash algorithm generates this value, we simply use -2 instead.

Comment: the link isn't exactly related but still very interesting